# Convert regex values in pandas to 0 or 1

Tags: python, regex, pandas, series

I have the below pandas column. I need to convert cells containing the word 'anaphylaxis' to 1 and the cells not containing the word to 0.

Till now I have tried but there is something missing

```
df['Name']= df['Name'].replace(r"^(.(?=anaphylaxis))*?$", 1,regex=True)
df['Name']= df['Name'].replace(r"^(.(?<!anaphylaxis))*?$", 0, regex=True)


ID             Name
84      Drug-induced anaphylaxis
1041    Acute anaphylaxis
1194    Anaphylactic reaction
1483    Anaphylactic reaction, due to adverse effect o...
2226    Anaphylaxis, initial encounter
2428    Anaphylaxis
2831    Anaphylactic shock
4900    Other anaphylactic reaction
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.contains` for case-insensitive matching.

```
import re
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.contains(r'anaphylaxis', flags=re.IGNORECASE).astype(int)
```

Or, more concisely,

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.contains(r'(?i)anaphylaxis').astype(int)
```

```
df
     ID  Name
0    84     1
1  1041     1
2  1194     0
3  1483     0
4  2226     1
5  2428     1
6  2831     0
7  4900     0
```

`contains` is useful when you want to also perform regex-based matching. Although in this case, you can probably get rid of the regex completely by adding `regex=False` for a bit more performance.

---

However, for even *more* performance, use a list comprehension.

```
df['Name'] = np.array(['anaphylaxis' in x.lower() for x in df['Name']], dtype=int)
```

Or even better,

```
df['Name'] = [1 if 'anaphylaxis' in x.lower() else 0 for x in df['Name'].tolist()]
```

```
df

     ID  Name
0    84     1
1  1041     1
2  1194     0
3  1483     0
4  2226     1
5  2428     1
6  2831     0
7  4900     0
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) instead of regex. This method returns a Boolean series, which we then convert to `int`.

```
df['Name']= df['Name'].str.contains('anaphylaxis', case=False, regex=False)\
                      .astype(int)
```

Result:

```
     ID  Name
0    84     1
1  1041     1
2  1194     0
3  1483     0
4  2226     1
5  2428     1
6  2831     0
7  4900     0
```